# C++11: does "decltype(1+2)" declare an xvalue or a prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, xvalue, prvalue

Does decltype(1+2) declare an xvalue or or a prvalue?

cppreference says, decltype(expression) will declare:
1. T&& if expression is an xvalue
2. T if expression is an prvalue
3. T& if expression is lvalue

But my question is: how to generate an expression that's an xvalue? I suppose that return value and temp objects should be xvalue, but actually they seem to be xvalue, in my experiment:

```
struct S{};
S f();
int main()
{
    int i=2;
    decltype(i+1) j=i;
    ++j;
    printf("i=%d\n",i);
    S obj;
    decltype(f()) k=obj;

    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles: I could judge that

> decltype(i+1) declares (i+1) as a prvalue

because if it's an xvalue, then decltype gets T&&, which cannot bind to a left value variable of "i". It's also weird that decltype(f()) is also giving me f() as a prvalue?

So my question is: how to write an expression so that decltype(expression) gives me an xvalue?
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue

Comment: You seem to be confusing several concepts. You cannot "declare" a value category. You declare variables with types. Value categories are properties of expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decltype resolves to a type, not an expression - you can't say that it "declares a prvalue" or anything like that.

`i+1` is a prvalue, and not an id-expression.  So `decltype` yields a non-reference type: `decltype(i+1) j = i;` means `int j = i;`.

The second case is similar; `f()` is a prvalue, so `decltype(f())` is `S`.

To get `decltype(expression)` to resolve to an rvalue reference type, the expression must be an xvalue. For example `decltype( std::move(f()) )` is `S&&`.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that `T` is not a reference type. Then:

- For `T f();`, the type `decltype(f())` is `T`.
- For `T& f();`, the type `decltype(f())` is `T&`.
- For `T&& f();`, the type `decltype(f())` is `T&&`.

So the way to get `decltype` to produce an rvalue reference is to apply it to an xvalue expression, for example, `std::move(1 + 2)`.

Comment: Isn't 1+2 a prvalue?

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, it is, why?

Comment: @user2357112 `std::move(prvalue)` gives xvalue

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misread that as `decltype(1+2)` rather than `std::move(1+2)`.